# Git Hub Actions Authentication with maven to private package registry of other repository

Tags: java, maven, github, github-actions

The project setup is as followed:

1. Project A (Some Java Application)
2. Project B (Some Java Library)

Both are built with maven. Project B publishes its package to the github package registry of its own repository. Project A has a dependency to the artifact from Project B in the pom.xml which looks somewhat like this:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.company</groupId>
   <artifactId>library-project-b</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Project A also includes the following repository reference to the package registry of Project B:

```
<repository>
   <id>github-library-project-b</id>
   <name>Project B Github packages repositories</name>
   <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/organization/library-project-b</url>
   <releases>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
   </releases>
   <snapshots>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
   </snapshots>
</repository>
```

For authenticating to the package registry of Porject B, Project A also includes a settings.xml which has the credentials set via environment variables that are provided via secrets from Github actions:

```
<server>
   <id>github-library-project-b</id>
   <username>${env.USER_PACKAGE_READ}</username>
   <password>${env.TOKEN_PACKAGE_READ}</password>
</server>
```

Inside the Continuous Integration Workflow in github actions I have the following step which maps the secrets from the repository for the registry access of project B to the environment variables which are used within the settings.xml and starts the build via mvn command:

```
- name: Build Package
  env:
     USER_PACKAGE_READ: ${{ secrets.USER_PACKAGE_READ }}
     TOKEN_PACKAGE_READ: ${{ secrets.TOKEN_PACKAGE_READ }}
  run: mvn -B --settings settings.xml clean package --file pom.xml -DskipTests
```

As I have read, that I can't use the GITHUB_TOKEN to access a package registry of another repository as the one the git hub action is run within, I have created a Personal Access token on my user account. (With package_read permission)

---

But no matter what I try - within the build stage, I will always end up with the following 401 error on the maven build command error trying to download the artifact:

```
Error:  Failed to execute goal on project PROjECT-A: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.company:ms-gp-events:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.company:library-project-b:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.company:library-project-b:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact com.company:library-project-b:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT from/to github-library-project-b (https://maven.pkg.github.com/organization/library-project-b): Authentication failed for https://maven.pkg.github.com/company/library-project-b/com/company/library-project-b/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/library-project-b-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom 401 Unauthorized -> [Help 1]
```

---

Has anyone a working example of a github actions workflow with maven that references a dependency which is stored within a github package registry from another private repository? I'm confused and frustrated that something so simple, takes so much time to setup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm still not absolutely sure, why my own settings.xml which was placed in the root of Project A did not work (maybe some missing configuration in the setup java step, but I won't do a root cause analysis there as I have not an infinit amount of time). I found a way around by using [maven-settings-action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/maven-settings-action) as "normal" step within github action:

```
 - uses: s4u/maven-settings-action@v2.3.0
        with:
          servers: |
            [{
                "id": "github-library-project-b",
                "username": "${{ secrets.USER_PACKAGE_READ }}",
                "password": "${{ secrets.TOKEN_PACKAGE_READ }}"
            }]
```

The action step will create the settings.xml within the user home directory:

```
Prepare maven settings: /home/runner/.m2/settings.xml
```

This settings.xml will eventually have effect and allow to auhtenticate against the package registry of Project B.

Comment: Does anyone know how to avoid setting  up username and password and use some kind of Github ssh key instead?

Comment: mine is not getting picked even after using `maven-settings-action`, is it a problem with the path?

Comment: Not sure. I have `maven-settings-action` still in place and it is working in my actions.